# Docker-compose expected container is up to date

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created docker-compose yaml file to run a docker image after it has been pulled locally and this yaml file contain another services (mysql and phpmyadmin) so when I run a command `docker-composer up -d` I found a conflict in creating a container as it been used by another container with the same name and I expected to show me that the container is already run and up to date, I know that the container must be removed or renamed before creating a new one but I aiming to get the newer version of image and check if mysql and phpmyadmin services is up or not if up gives me those container is up to date and if not create it as another environment bellow.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app-prod:
    image: prod:1.0
    container_name: app-prod
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    links:
      - db-prod
    depends_on:
      - db-prod
      - phpmyadmin-prod

  db-prod:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: db-prod
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - db-prod:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin-prod:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.0.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db-prod
    container_name: phpmyadmin-prod
    ports:
      - "5001:80"

volumes:
  db-prod:
```

**Error**

```
Creating phpmyadmin-prod ... error
Creating db-prod         ... 

ERROR: for phpmyadmin-prod  Cannot create container for service phpmyadmin: Conflict. The container name "/phpmyadmin-prod" is already in use by container "5a52b27b64f7302bccb1c3a0eaeca8a33b3dfee5f1a279f6a809695Creating db-prod         ... error

ERROR: for db-prod  Cannot create container for service db: Conflict. The container name "/db-prod" is already in use by container "5d01c21efafa757008d1b4dbcc8d09b4341ac1457a0ca526ee57873cd028cf2b". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

ERROR: for phpmyadmin  Cannot create container for service phpmyadmin: Conflict. The container name "/phpmyadmin-prod" is already in use by container "5a52b27b64f7302bccb1c3a0eaeca8a33b3dfee5f1a279f6a809695f482500a9". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: Conflict. The container name "/db-prod" is already in use by container "5d01c21efafa757008d1b4dbcc8d09b4341ac1457a0ca526ee57873cd028cf2b". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Error: No such container: app-prod
Error: No such container: app-prod
```

While using another docker-compose file for test environment I got this which I expected

```
db-stage is up-to-date
phpmyadmin-stage is up-to-date
Creating app-stage ... done
```

Comment: check `docker ps` and remove the conflicting containers. Then retry.

Comment: I do so but I don't need every time I run docker-compose up command to remove those container I just remove only the first service as this app-prod service contain the code changes and I want the other containers to keep up all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have several docker-compose files and I run this command `docker-composer -f <compose_file_path> -p <project_name> -d up` and then I try to run `docker-composer up -d` in the same location without specify the project name `-p <project_name>` which gives me the conflict of the container as this make the compose-file up with a different project name and with the same container name.

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose run command will create new containers. But in your case, 2 of them are already running, hence, you can use

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Sorry I means up changed

Comment: Can try adding --no-recreate flag to the docker-compose up command

Comment: The same conflict error

Comment: What is your docker & docker-compose version?

Comment: Docker version 20.10.12 , docker-compose version 1.25.0

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in docker-compose, I am using the same docker version but the docker-compose version is 1.29.2, it works for me, can you try docker-compose start

Comment: Starting db-prod         ... failed
Starting phpmyadmin-prod ... failed
Starting app-prod        ... failed
ERROR: No containers to start

Comment: Update  docker-compose version to 1.29.2 and I have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That specific error is easy to fix.  You're trying to manually specify `container_name:` for every container, but the error message says you have existing containers with those same names already.  Left to its own, Compose will assign non-conflicting names, and you can almost always just delete `container_name:` from the Compose file.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: prod:1.0
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    depends_on: [db, phpmyadmin]
    # no container_name: or links:
  db: { ... }
  phpmyadmin: { ... }
```

The other obvious point of conflict for running the same Compose file in multiple places is the `ports:`; only one container or host process can listen on a given (first) port number.  If you're trying to run the same Compose file multiple times on the same system you might need some way to replace the port numbers.  This could be a place where using [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) fits in well: define a base `docker-compose.yml` that defines the services but not any of the ports, and an override file that assigns specific host ports.

Comment: Your answer is logically but I have the same docker-compose file with another environment for testing and when I try ```docker-compose up -d``` it doesn't give me a conflict this means that when docker compose up it give me that the containers is already running not a conflict, this environment when I up the compose file it try to create another container with the same name of container that exists and I did not know why this happen.